# 2024 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, featured, election

[Moderator election #3](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/election/3) — your "graduation" election — on Quantum Computing has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Tristan Nemoz]

[image: glS]

[image: Mithrandir24601]

They will show up on [the moderators tab](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5396875531255808).

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks! :D